# How come the graphics is not drawing onto the panel

Tags: c#, graphics, panel

I want to draw a grid in my panel. The graphics object (screen) that i created with bitmap isn't drawing in my panel. I tried with debugging to look if the screen wasn't drawing but that wasn't the case.

I tried creating the graphic object from the panel createGraphic method and the parameter `painteventargs` from the panel paint method. Both times when I used it  to draw it with `OnPaint` it took too long.

```cs
public Main()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    backBuffer = new Bitmap(drawPanel.Width, drawPanel.Height);
    screen = Graphics.FromImage(backBuffer);
    sizeGridPoints = 2;
    lenghtBetweenGridPoints = 10;
}

protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);
    screen.Clear(Color.Black);
    DrawGrid();
}

private void DrawGrid()
{
    for(int x = lenghtBetweenGridPoints; x < drawPanel.Width; x += lenghtBetweenGridPoints)
    {
        for(int y = lenghtBetweenGridPoints; y < drawPanel.Height; y+= lenghtBetweenGridPoints)
        {
            screen.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(Color.Green), x, y, sizeGridPoints, sizeGridPoints);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using the Paint event is fine but caching or creating a Graphics object for drawing almost never is. Use the e.Graphics object from the Paint arguments and pass it out the the drawing functions! - Or Draw into a Bitmap. But that means you are changing that bitmap for good; a bad idea for dynamically drawing varying data..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a `Graphics` object from a bitmap, it will draw on this bitmap, not on your user interface. Instead, use the `Graphics` object from the `PaintEventArgs e` of your `OnPaint` method, to draw directly on the form or a control.

```
e.Graphics.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(Color.Green), x, y, sizeGridPoints, sizeGridPoints);
```

You should never create your own `Graphics` object.

Create your own grid control:

```
public class GridPanel : Panel
{
    public GridPanel()
    {
        DoubleBuffered = true; // Speeds up drawing, e.g. when panel is resized.

        // Set default colors
        BackColor = Color.Black;
        ForeColor = Color.Green;
    }

    private int _lenghtBetweenGridPoints = 20;
    public int LenghtBetweenGridPoints
    {
        get { return _lenghtBetweenGridPoints; }
        set {
            if (value != _lenghtBetweenGridPoints) {
                _lenghtBetweenGridPoints = value;
                Invalidate(); // Redraw the grid.
            }
        }
    }

    private int _sizeGridPoints = 3;
    public int SizeGridPoints
    {
        get {
            return _sizeGridPoints;
        }
        set {
            if (value != _sizeGridPoints) {
                _sizeGridPoints = value;
                Invalidate(); // Redraw the grid.
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        // e.Graphics.Clear(Color.Black); Not necessary. We use the BackColor of the panel.
        if (LenghtBetweenGridPoints > 0 && SizeGridPoints > 0) {
            e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias; // Optional.
            using (var brush = new SolidBrush(ForeColor)) { // We use the ForeColor of the panel.
                for (int x = LenghtBetweenGridPoints; x < Width; x += LenghtBetweenGridPoints) {
                    for (int y = LenghtBetweenGridPoints; y < Height; y += LenghtBetweenGridPoints) {
                        e.Graphics.FillEllipse(brush, x, y, SizeGridPoints, SizeGridPoints);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Once it has been compiled, it will automatically appear in toolbox window and you can drag and drop it on your form. You will even be able to edit the properties `LenghtBetweenGridPoints` and `SizeGridPoints` in the properties window.

You could also simply use the already available `BackColor` and `ForeColor` properties of the panel for the grid. This would allow you to set the colors in the properties window as well. Don't forget to dispose brushes that you have created.

---

Important: Do not call `OnPaint` directly. Instead, call the `Invalidate` or `Refresh` methods of the object you want to redraw. The point is that Windows decides when to call `OnPaint`. E.g. if `Invalidate` is called too frequently (e.g. 5 times in 1/60 seconds), Windows might decide to not call `OnPaint` every time, as this would create lag. On the other hand, when the user resizes the panel, Windows will call `OnPaint` automatically. If you restore a window that was minimized, this will re-paint the control as well. Otherwise it would remain black.

Comment: why create a class for such a simple thing?? The errors in the op should be understood and corrected instead. Also: Why create the same brush so many times?

Comment: Creating classes is the most natural thing to in object oriented programming. Here it is not just a class, but a reusable, configurable control encapsulating the whole drawing logic. Of course I should have moved the brush creation out of the loops. I corrected it.

Comment: Yes, classes are a natural thing but the issue here was a simple&common newbie  error. If any real responsibilities/knowlegde comes up to be put into the class, ok, but so far there is nothing in sight..

Comment: My aim was not just to fix the error, but to suggest a general code improvement. As you said, the OP is a newbie and showing him how he can easily create his own controls cannot be wrong.